# ssh: how to turn off echo when run a command in the remote

Tags: ssh

I would like to use ssh to run the following command on the remote server

```
ssh myserver kinit
```

The command `kinit` is to initialize a kerberos ticket, which involves typing in password. If it is run on the remote server, the password won't show on the screen. Yet, if the command is called from ssh, the password would show.

Wonder whether there is any way to let ssh turn off echoing key presses. Searched ssh document, but didn't find a solution. Not sure whether it is doable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Force a terminal to be passed along so `kinit` can perform the terminal-no-echo thing it otherwise does by default:

```
ssh -t myserver kinit
```